# Partition of the $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=\{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ in pairs $(a,b)$ where $b-a=$ constant $\pmod{p}$, with $p$ an odd prime.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

thank you very much for your answers to my question posted in "Partition of the set $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=\{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ in pairs $(a,b)$ where $b-a=$ constant $\pmod{p}$, with $p$ an odd prime." (23-November)

I especially appreciated that some of you related this problem to graph theory. I had already solved the question when the difference is the same for all possible pairs of elements and I liked very much to see that by using graph theory the question has a much faster and clearer answer than what I had initially thought.

But the main question remains and I probably wasn't clear when asking it; I should have made a more detailed example.

I start by always  fixing a first pair of the form $(1,a)$. In $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ I find six possible configurations where the difference $k$ between pairs (mod 7) is the same: fixing a pair of the form $(1,a)$ and permuting the positions of the other pairs, I get

$(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)$ and $(1,2),(5,6),(3,4)$ (here $k=1$),

$(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)$ and $(1,4), (3,6),(2,5)$ (here $k=3$)

$(1,6),(4,2),(5,3)$ and $(1,6), (5,3), (4,2)$ (here $k=5$).

I get $6=3!$ distinct possibilities.

In $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ the possible differences between pairs of elements are $k=1,4,5,8,9$ and writing down all the possible configurations I get $120=5!$

For example, for $k=1$: $$(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),$$ but also $$(1,2),(7,8),(3,4),(5,6),(9,10)$$ is acceptable.
Or for $k=4$ one can have $$(1,5),(3,7),(4,8),(9,2),6,10),$$ but also $$(1,5),(6,10),(9,2),(3,7),(4,8)$$ is acceptable. And a lot more: as I said considering all possible $k$, there are 120 sequences of pairs.

In $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$ I checked and I will have $11!$ possibilities. Thus, in many cases the number of configurations is given by $\frac{p-1}{2}!$

But that does not happen always. In $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ I'm not going to have $720=6!$ possibilities, but instead 3816.
I could not fully check the case $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ but in this case the number will be greater than $9!$.

What I want to ask is whether in the cases where this number is higher than $\frac{p-1}{2}!$  if someone has any idea about how to get these sequences of pairs and also about some possible formula to count them.

Comment: To check, in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, why can't we have $k = 2$? EG $(2, 4), (6, 1), (3, 5)$. It seems like you want to fix the pair $(1, b)$, as opposed to allowing for the pair $(a, 1)$.

Comment: That is correct. I am always fixing the pair $(1,b)$. And in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (or $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ the $k$ is the same for all pairs, which explains the numbers $3!$ and $5!$. But in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}=\{1,2,…,11,12\}$ I have (as an example): $(1,9), (2,10), (8,3)$, (difference is $k=8$) and also $(7,6), (5,4), (12,11)$ (difference is $k=12$). That is why in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ I have more than $6!$ sequences of pairs.

Comment: FWIW The solution write-ups make a lot of sense to me. However, it's unclear to me what you're trying to say EG 1) At no point in the question do you define that we must have the pair $(1, b)$, which invalidates my $k=2$ example. 2) For $Z_7 $ and $k=1, 3, 5$, I don't understand why here are $3!$ distinct possibilities.  Perhaps again you are forcing $(1,b)$ to be the first term, but again not stating it? If that's the case, then yes there are $(p-1)/2!$ ways to permute $(p-1)/2$ elements (which are these pairs).

Comment: 3) Is "distinct possibilities" referring to a fixed $k$ value? If so, that's not stated, and your presentation of all valid $k$ confuses what you're getting at. (IE The true number of possibitlies of $Z_7$ with your unwritten conditions should be $ 3 \times6 = 18$??? ) $\quad$ Unfortunately, we're not yet mind readers, so I'd encourage you to be clearer in your writeup, and ensure that everything you're thinking of is explicitly stated.

Comment: You are right and I apologize. I will try to add some comments later, explaining my question better (I hope).